# STM32F0 restart by itself

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, reset, stm32f0

My STM32F051C8T6 is restarting spontaneously every about 400ms. NRST pin is decoupled with 100nF capacitor. I think that it isn't hardware reset - even with 220R pull-up it is still restarting. Watchdog is disabled. Microcontroler can be programmed. I'm programming it with ST-Link Utility using only SWDIO and SWCLK without RESET. What can cause this problem?

The code:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : main.c
  * Description        : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2017 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/**
  * @}
*/ 

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

UPDATE:

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"

int main(void)
{
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;     // Enable clock for Port B
    GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0;   // Output
    GPIOB->BSRR = (1<<6);                  // Turning LED on

    for(;;);
}
```

Here is updated, simpler code. It is still self-reseting but it is one difference: when I program target with first HAL code LED is turning off for shorter time than with code written on registers. I'm afraid that microcontroller is damaged physically.

UPDATE 2

I removed old microcontroller and soldered new one. After few hours, situation repeated. Here is solution:

1. Open ST-Link Utility.
2. Target -> Option Bytes -> Flash sectors protection -> Unselect All.
3. Target -> Option Bytes -> User configuration option byte ->  check "WDG_SW" option.
4. Full chip erase.

Comment: Maybe your code ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you haven't provided any source code or schematic diagram.

Comment: I tried with "clean" code and it is still happening

Comment: What is "clean" code?

Comment: Code with only one output used, without other perifieries. Output is used to turn on LED

Comment: Show your "clean" code.

Comment: ANd check your Vcc and ground

Comment: Vcc is ok (3.3V) as same as GND

Comment: I see you set the interrupt for the clock, but I don't see a handler?

Comment: @Trevor If I recall correctly, STM guys are providing a `weak` definitions of the interrupt handlers somewhere. It might be the case here.

Comment: do you have a watch dog timer running?

Comment: No, watchdog is disabled.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with a STM32L051C8T. Has there been any resolution in the mean time?
Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 5):

To know why the chip resets, you should check the reset flags on boot.
`6.4.10 Control/status register (RCC_CSR)` in the ["reference manual"](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/c2/f8/8a/f2/18/e6/43/96/DM00031936.pdf/files/DM00031936.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031936.pdf).

The other thing you'd want to know when it happens is an Hardfault. Although by default this would cause a hang or a watchdog reset.
Look up information about the hardfault in the ["programming manual"](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/fc/90/c7/17/a1/44/43/89/DM00051352.pdf/files/DM00051352.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00051352.pdf).

Depending on you debugger, you might also want to enable the VectorCatch during the initialization script of the debug session. [Keil example.](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3782.htm) Vectorcatch triggers a breakpoint on fault handler entry.

[Manuals.](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f051c8.html)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I should check which flag is on in RCC_CSR register when reset occurs? Thanks to this I can tell  source of this behaviour? I'm trying to debugg in STM32 eclipse workbench but I can't read register status.